# Node js express 500 server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

When i try to make a call to a method exposed through nodejs server i got 500 error
it says protocol version not supported

The call to the method was working perfect if i remove the socket.io configration...

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/pollapp'));

app.get('/pollapp/PollServer.js', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.htm');
});

app.get('/pollapp/PollServer.js/api/listPoll', function (req, res) {
    //....code
});

var io = require('./hostedSocket').listen(server);

io.configure(function () {
    io.set('resource', '/pollapp/PollServer.js'); //Where we'll listen for connections.
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Here call to /pollapp/PollServer.js/api/listPoll gives me 500 server error (Protocol version not supported)

but if i remove

```
    io.configure(function () {
        io.set('resource', '/pollapp/PollServer.js');
    });
```

then things are working well and good.
But if i remove the io.configure then socket is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to mix the `socket.io` resource location with Express routes, which – judging by the `socket.io` code *and* the errors you're getting – isn't going to work.

What happens is that any request starting with `/pollapp/PollServer.js` will be handled by `socket.io`, and *not* get passed to Express.

So you need to keep those two paths separated. Perhaps this works better (untested):

```
io.set('resource', '/pollapp/PollServer.js/socket.io');
```

And in your client:

```
<script src="/pollapp/PollServer.js/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Although I wonder why you're not just using the default `/socket.io` resource value.